# How to change url mapping to route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a help page on my site and user can view it with this url

```
www.mydomain/home/help
```

now I want my user see this URL at their browser

```
www.mydomain/help
```

my controller name is "home" and my action name is "help" I can handle it by using URL mapping on my web.config and it works fine

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
   <add url="~/Help" mappedUrl="~/Home/Help"/>
 </urlMappings>
```

but if I want to handle it with my route how can I change my route or add what route, I added this route but it works not

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "myroute",
            url: "home",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Help" }
        );
```

what is my fault with my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To auto map `http://yourdomain.com/help` to `http://yourdomain.com/home/help`

**Case 1:**
If you use `<urlMapping />` in configuration

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
   <add url="~/Help" mappedUrl="~/Home/Help"/>
 </urlMappings>
```

url template should tell about controller and action parameter mappings, change url like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "myroute",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Help" }
        );
```

or

**Case 2:**
 without `<urlMapping />` you can manage with `MapRoute` like below

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HelpRoute",
            url: "help/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Help" }
        );
```

Please see below page for more details with routing examples

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: ,i test it without url mapping like Case 2 but i got this error: The resource cannot be found.

Comment: You may have other route mappings in RouteConfig with one url token

Comment: Now I updated the Case 2 and added reference link for more examples, please give a try

Answer (score 1):

You can create specific route for `yourdomain.com/help`:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Help",
     url: "help",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Help" }
 );
```